# Admin-on-REST: Nested Create-Route not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

my current setup looks like this:

***httpClient.js:***

```
import { fetchUtils } from 'admin-on-rest'

const HttpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' })
    }

    // ...handle authorization and set some header

    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options)
}

export default HttpClient
```

***restClient.js***

```
import { jsonServerRestClient } from 'admin-on-rest'
import HttpClient from './httpClient.js'

export default jsonServerRestClient('', HttpClient)
```

...so I'm pretty basic in that department.

What I now have is a couple of ***routes*** looking like this:

```
<Route exact path="/stream" render={(routeProps) => <StreamList hasCreate resource="stream" {...routeProps} />} />,
<Route exact path="/stream/create" render={(routeProps) => <StreamCreate resource="stream" {...routeProps} />} />,
<Route exact path="/stream/:id" render={(routeProps) => <StreamEdit hasDelete resource="stream" {...routeProps} />} />,
<Route exact path="/stream/:id/delete" render={(routeProps) => <Delete resource="stream" {...routeProps} />} />,
<Route exact path="/stream/query/:id" component={StreamQueryEdit} />,
```

...this is all pretty standard as well and works fine.

***My problem*** now is that I have another route `/config/what`, where I want to have nested routes for one of the resources. The routing looks like this:

```
<Route exact path="/config/how/antonym" render={(routeProps) => <AntonymList hasCreate resource="antonym" {...routeProps} />} />
<Route exact path="/config/how/antonym/create" render={(routeProps) => <AntonymCreate resource="antonym" {...routeProps} />} />
<Route exact path="/config/how/antonym/:id" render={(routeProps) => <AntonymEdit resource="antonym" {...routeProps} />} />
<Route exact path="/config/how/antonym/:id/delete" render={(routeProps) => <Delete resource="antonym" {...routeProps} />} />
```

Inside the `/config/how/` these nested routes are rendered like this:

```
if (this.props.children) {
    return this.props.children
}
```

The List-, Edit- and Delete-Route all work like expected here. The only problem is that once I navigate to the Create-Route I get a 500-error from the server.

Turns out that after some investigating, the framework does not recognize this route as a create Route but instead thinks of it as a `GET` request for the id of "create".

Here is what I tracked the issue down to:
[image: AOR debug]

This suggests that for some reason admin-on-rest thinks of this request as a GET request. This also causes the code to go through `Edit.js` (instead of "Create"?) And I'm really not sure why.

I tried to find the place where the `type` parameters are being set to see what might cause this behaviour ...but no luck so far.

It's especially weird that both the list and the edit route work fine in these cases. It's just the create-route...

Comment: Bug reports should be asked on the aor github page. Make an issue there

Comment: hi @kunalpareek ...well, to be honest I was/am not sure if this is an actual bug or I'm just doing something wrong here...

Comment: I have had some problems with nested routes myself. I got around it by creating a dummy resource in the rest client and then setting the correct  URL there.

Comment: They closed the issue and sent me back to stackoverflow without even commenting on whether it's a bug or my doing something wrong @kunalpareek :D

Comment: Yeah they do that quite liberally :) You should see how Frenchly Francois shuts down peeps with zany ideas. Sometimes they don't though. Thought this might be one of them.

Comment: I haven't used custom routing with AOR at all and have zero insight into how it all comes together unfortunately. Some comp upstream is shooting the wrong type for your request. 

How I debug these kinds of problems usually is by following the component code in the src folder in node modules, and then writing logs in the roughly equivalent place for the component in the lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure for your AntonymCreate component it has a form like this:

```
export const AntonymCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props} title="Create">
    ...
    </Create>
);
```

This is probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately my create-route already looks like that. Since I can't post code in a comment, I'll provide a screenshot instead: [https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GD8JoSK.png](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GD8JoSK.png).